# How to custom HTML form_errors in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I would like custom the render of form_errors in Symfony 3, because I would like obtain (in my Twig remplate) :

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">My error</div>
```

Instead of :

```
<ul><li>My error</li></ul>
```

It's possible ?

**I tried this :**

```
{{ form_errors(form.name) ? '<div class="alert alert-danger">' ~ form_errors(form.name) ~ '</div>' : ''  }}
```

But the HTML is not interpreted and it may not be very clean ..

**And this (Recovery of vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Resources\views\Form\form_div_layout.html.twig line 307):**

**I overloaded:**

```
{%- block form_errors -%}
    {%- if errors|length > 0 -%}
    <ul>
        {%- for error in errors -%}
            <li>{{ error.message }}</li>
        {%- endfor -%}
    </ul>
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endblock form_errors -%}
```

**By :**

```
{%- block form_errors -%}
{%- if errors|length > 0 -%}
<ul>
    {%- for error in errors -%}
        <li>{{ error.message }}</li>
    {%- endfor -%}
</ul>
{%- endif -%}
{%- endblock form_errors -%}
```

But the variable "error" is not defined

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Are you trying to add this block in the same Twig template as your form?

Comment: Yes, I solved my problem thanks to this :) http://www.webtipblog.com/override-symfony-2-form-element-twig-template/

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this website:

https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-forms/form-theme-create#play

You need to modify below file

`vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig`

and search for the `{% block form_errors -%}` block to modify it.

you can look here for more informations:

https://codereviewvideos.com/course/beginner-s-guide-to-symfony-3-forms/video/styling-and-customising-using-form-fragments

But this is not the right method, the good one is to override this file by copy that block into another twig template, modify it and call this template into the twig template of your page.

Here are the explanations:

https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-forms/form-theme-create#play